# How to setup an Azure Windows VM for multiple users to RDP to their unique MS Access file?

Tags: windows, sql-server, azure, microsoft-access

I have 2 Azure VMs. One will act as an application server. The application is an Access file. This Access file connects to a separate Microsoft SQL Server database on a different Azure VM which will be the database server. On the application server, there will be multiple copies of the same Access file. There will be only 1 O365 user per Access file. These Windows users will RDP to the Azure application VM. When they connect, they should see only their Access file. Their Access file is connected to their database on the other server. For every Access file, there is a unique database and SQL user on the Azure SQL server instance. This is a simple architecture, I know. My question is how do I set up the Azure Windows application VM so that each user can only see and log into their particular Access file?

- This question was [previously closed on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73130578/how-to-setup-windows-vm-for-multiple-users) as off-topic. While I did not intend that to be the case, I'm used to using Stack Overflow as programmer and I'm not much of a sysadmin or technician as you can tell by my question, lol. For now, I'm treating the one comment I received over there as an answer as it may solve the problem just fine. But, I'm definitely open to suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Application Collection's feature of the RDS's role.

That way you can create 10 application link that point to a shortcut that open Access with the corrects file.

You configure security on each application to allow only the one you want for the resource.

You could watch that link, which give some hint on how to do. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wln_Dvts_vQ

Comment: Thanks, I watched the video and I understand the basics of setting up an RDS role. If I can create a shortcut to each unique Access file, that would potentially work. Will it allow me to create more than 10 user shortcut links using this approach? The Microsoft users will have Office 365 business accounts but will be in different domains I guess. Unless I can also set-up a DC in Azure and add existing Office 365 users to it?

Comment: Yes you will have to authentificate the user against your own domain as most probably these user would use the rdweb feature, aka accessing your app via a webpage.

Comment: @Darlirium Yes for more than 10. You are limited legally by the Windows RDP CAL you have.